# Where, in automysqlbackup, do I add mysqldump parameters?

Tags: backup, mysql

How to stop  automysqlbackup's cron.daily script -- as installed and configured from `apt-get install automysqlbackup` -- throwing the following error:

```
 mysqldump: Got error: 1142: SELECT,LOCK TABL command denied to user 
'debian-sys-maint'@'localhost' for table 'cond_instances' when using LOCK TABLES
```

This occurs after having upgraded to MySQL 5.5 as a side-effect of having  upgraded to Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.

The correct solution (thanks @sr_ for pointer to the appropriate bug report) is to exclude the 'performance_schema' database from mysqldump.

So the question is: How to do this whilst respecting the Debian packages and configurations?

The problem occurs daily  after having upgraded to MySQL 5.5.

**Background:**
My aim is to stay with the Ubuntu Debian-installed packages and configurations in as standard a manner as possible. But actually, this is a bug with the way the packages are installed / upgraded, so it is necessary to update one of the supplied configuration files.

`debian-sys-maint` has fullest privileges anyway, so already has sufficient to lock each table before dumping it.

What's confusing is that `/usr/share/doc/automysqlbackup/README.Debian` says that

> All parameters can be setup by editing the /etc/default/automysqlbackup file

`/etc/default/automysqlbackup` invokes mysqlbackup with settings in  `/etc/mysql/debian.cnf` which says:

> Automatically generated for Debian scripts. DO NOT TOUCH!.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This solution has fixed it for me.

According to [this bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/automysqlbackup/+bug/995587?comments=all) it is necessary to stop automysqlbackup dumping the 'performance_schema' database, and this is done by editing `/etc/default/automysqlbackup` as follows:

Add an additional pipe to grep step to remove the 'performance_schema' from the list of DBNAMES.

So, in the line that starts `DBNAMES=`, and after `| grep -v ^mysql$` insert

```
| grep -v ^performance_schema$
```

before `| tr \\\r\\\n ,\`

Thanks to Jérôme Drouet

This solution applies to the Debian version of automysqlbackup as in Ubuntu 12.04. Evidently the syntax for excluding the "performance_schema" database varies per Linux distro -- see @stat below.

Answer (score 1):

### Edit: Forget everything I said.

See [this bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/automysqlbackup/+bug/995587).  Perhaps you find a way to "to exclude the 'performance_schema' database from mysqldump" as comment #2 indicates; otherwise the poster of the bug reports edited the `automysqlbackup` script to add the `--skip-lock-tables` parameter, but I suppose this can hurt you (as laid out below).

---

Short answer: You probably **want** to lock them.

I guess *not locking* them is not what you want since it could get you useless backups, i.e. when something changes the table *while backing it up is in progress* --- which is what the *lock* is there to prevent.

[This fork's README](https://github.com/mcheck/automysqlbackup) as well as [this block entry](http://dylansserver.com/note/automysqlbackup) mention something about granting the user `'autobackup'@'localhost'` access to **lock tables**.

That said, your error message indicates that the "user" in question actually is `'debian-sys-maint'@'localhost'`.  **So I guess** if you grant the needed priviledges to *this* user **or** change the credentials of the backup script in [`automysqlbackup.conf`](https://github.com/mcheck/automysqlbackup/blob/master/automysqlbackup.conf) (which might be `/etc/default/automysqlbackup` in Debian, consult `man automysqlbackup` and `/usr/share/doc/automysqlbackup/README.Debian`), you should be fine.

---

**Edit**
From [this manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_lock-tables) I quote what `--lock-tables` is supposed to do

> `--lock-tables, -l`
>
> For each dumped database, lock all tables to be dumped before dumping them.

It's linked from the only occurrence of `--skip-lock-tables` in the manual, so I take it to mean that `--skip-lock-tables` causes `mysqldump` to *not lock tables when dumping them*.  This, as I argued above, is not advisable.
I do not think it has anything to do with **dumping lock tables** but with **locking tables**.

I don't, however, understand why it doesn't work if, as you said, the user in question should be able to do it...

Answer (score 1):

**I was mistaken see solution 1 which does indeed work on debian**

I was able to fix this "temporarily" by changing the line in 
`/etc/default/automysqlbackup` to the following:

```
CONFIG_db_exclude=( 'information_schema' 'performance_schema' )
```

I am not sure what effect this has but test restorations work for me and the backup completes without errors.

After the last update my solution which was on debian sid failed but solution one (which did not work for me before) does work.  That is grepping the /etc/default/automysqlbackup and adding the line | grep -v ^performance_schema$. The above excludes that I used before seem to be ignored in the dump.

Comment: What distro does your solution apply to?

Comment: Sorry, should have included that pretty important.  This is on aptosid and so this might be a sid only fix.